# Posting data with Android and HTTPSURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I realize that there are numerous posts about how to POST json data using Android and HttpURLConnection. However regardless of what I tried, my POST body seems to never arrive / magically disappear. I was hoping somebody could advise me:

```
    // Encrypt the post data
    String ciphertext = Crypt.encrypt(postData, encryptionKey);

    int postDataLength = ciphertext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
    byte[] bCipertext = ciphertext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // Establish connection
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


    // Set the request method
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // Set headers
    for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
        conn.setRequestProperty(key, headers.get(key).trim());
    }

    // Set content type - always application/json!
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // Set UTF-8 as the charset
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/" + "POST");

    // Don't cache data
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // Expect output
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    if (!postData.isEmpty()) {
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Set content length
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postDataLength);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(ciphertext);
        out.close();
    }
```

Sample ciphertext:

iMUPu3dJZRtwofMAeAzr5OvuNU2jg8kJL4I3LEtidlD18JG3ijg5m9vMON-Jndqt3fQLPotORB3ibmWl3-ia3lX5RyJIwPi7CCbNhkoVYHZEMktgC_N_6hqu4hYCMieLxvI93NwGMAsNpd00TNGFVSf0G3blpgRQ-gM5doxq6WRwkGlspZgHgQBK0GhXs3tNDGuBTYMJZHo3lKVR6k5Nky9JfeSyat7B7wO1-dFbVqr9DOy16mjRSlVKPzY_x1P63e9CQfnAc1sP8Yc2rvVXToC_Aq_OyQR1FZxHWi3Z9wA=,J83haIWVSXDmtQ3UxPzaFQ==

EDIT:
The problem persists with OKHttp:

```
 Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8"), ciphertext))
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    System.out.println(ciphertext);

    String output = response.body().string();
    System.out.println(output);

    // Decrypt
    String decryptedResponse = null;
    try {
        decryptedResponse = Crypt.decrypt(output.toString(), encryptionKey).trim();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // If the response wasn't encrypted, then we will receive an exception
        decryptedResponse = output.toString();
    }

    HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
    resp.setStatus(response.code());
```

PHP receiving the request is, in essence, just this:

print_r($_POST);

Comment: Show your php script.

Comment: 'conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");' ? You are not sending json.  'conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/" + "POST");'??? That would be contradicting. But also it does not exist. Better try form url encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a third party library to work with HTTP requests. Eg okhttp dramatically reduces the code overhead and amount or errors:

```
String postBody = ""
    + "Releases\n"
    + "--------\n"
    + "\n"
    + " * _1.0_ May 6, 2013\n"
    + " * _1.1_ June 15, 2013\n"
    + " * _1.2_ August 11, 2013\n";

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://api.github.com/markdown/raw")
    .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, postBody))
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

This snippet is taken from: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: Thanks Moritz - unfortunately the problem persists. Updated answer with OKHttp code

Comment: Where does your request stale? Have you checked server logs?

Comment: The problem is that the $_POST body is empty. Nothing is being posted.

Comment: It's basically just a print_r $_POST;